# TypeScript: Object.keys() on object with pre-known keys has too general type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

I am learning TypeScript and one thing that is hard for me to understand is how to correctly iterate over an object's keys. A very common application is something like this:

```js
type T = {
    "a": number,
    "b": number
}

const obj : T = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

const keys = Object.keys(obj);
const m = keys.map(k => 2*obj[k]);
```

I have an object `obj` of known type `T` and want to get all keys to call `map` on them. The return type of `Object.keys([type T])` is `string[]` according to Visual Studio Code. I read elsewhere that the reason for this is that the object passed to `Object.keys` could be a subtype of `T`. However, in this example it is clear that the object has type `T` and not a subtype (with more keys).

Due to the too general return type the TS compiler shows me an error when using the keys in `map` to read the actual values for each key. This makes sense as only "a" and "b" are allowed, but the compiler thinks any other string could also occur (which is wrong, at least in this example)

What is the recommended way to call `map` on the keys of an Object? Casting the type using this method works:

```
function getKeysGen<T extends object>(o: T) {
    return Object.keys(o) as Array<keyof T>;
}

const keys = getKeysGen(obj); // correctly shown as Type ("a" | "b")
```

I don't even have to specify the type when calling the generic key getter, TS/VSCode seems to be able to infer it from the type of the parameter itself. But why does that not already work for the original `Object.keys` function?

And why does this not work?

```js
function getKeys(o: Object) {
    return Object.keys(o) as Array<keyof typeof o>;
}
const keys = getKeys(obj); // VSCode shows the type is ("constructor" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "valueOf" | "hasOwnProperty" | "isPrototypeOf" | "propertyIsEnumerable")[]
```

When I run this code `keys` actually contains `[ 'a', 'b' ]` and not the key that VSCode showed me. However, when using the keys to map the values to their double, the TS compiler says no:

```
const m = keys.map(k => 2*obj[k]);
```

The error is

> error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

Most likely because the type of `k` is not inferred correctly, so something like `2*undefined` can occur.

Is the generic function `getKeysGen` I wrote above the way to go or is there any catch that I am missing?

Comment: This may be because you are trying to multiply a number with a character

Comment: But the values of the object are numbers and not characters

Answer (score 3):

The type definition for `Object.keys` is indeed too general for what you're looking for. If you look in `lib.es2015.cor.d.ts`, you see:

```
keys(o: {}): string[];
```

`string[]` isn't good enough.

For something like this, I think the easiest thing to do would be to assert that the keys *really are* the keys of the object when you collect them:

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[];
```

For your `getKeysGen` function, an issue is that `Object` is the Object constructor, you want `object` instead - but even then, you can't get to the type of the object passed *with each call of the function* without generics. Otherwise, you just have `keyof typeof o` where `o` is a plain object.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the definition is so general? Is there no way for TypeScript to see which type the object has and from this knowledge infer the type of its keys?

Comment: I assume you mean `getKeys` instead of `getKeysGen`? When I change the parameter type of my function from `Object` to `object` Visual Studio Code suddenly shows me `never[]` as the return type. Why is that?