# How to have typescript validate keys of known type in switch case?

Tags: typescript, switch-statement

I have the following situation:

```
interface SomeType {
  a: //doesn't matter,
  b: //doesn't matter,
  c: //doesn't matter,
}
const someType: SomeType = //doesn't matter
Object.keys(someType).map(key => {
  switch(key){
    case 'some key that doesnt exist in SomeType': //how do I make typescript complain about this?
  }
});
```

As the question in the comment asks, how do I go about this so that typescript can know that the only valid cases are `a`, `b`, and `c`, and complain that I'm adding a case which isn't possible given `SomeType`?

Comment: You might just want  to assign `key` to a new variable `k` while asserting that `k` is `keyof SomeType`: https://tsplay.dev/Wy606w

Comment: Object.keys has [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452798/typescript-object-keys-on-object-with-pre-known-keys-has-too-general-type), which leads to Object.keys being `string[]` instead of the predefined keys you have.

Comment: @LeoDog896 "Type erasure" refers to how TS transpiles to JS without encoding the type system in the emitted code; it has nothing to do with what's going on with `Object.keys()`.  But aside from terminology you have indeed identified what is going on: `Object.keys()` returns `string[]`.  The reasoning is that object types are open/extendible and not sealed/exact, so an object of type `SomeType` has *at least* keys `a`, `b`, and `c`, but it might have more than those.

Comment: OP: See the linked questions and answers... you either need a type assertion (where you claim the object has no excess properties) or to do something other than `Object.keys()` (like starting with a hardcoded const array of keys).  Both shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4n9XN)